# Is their any speed penalty to use .club (or similar) domain extension instead of well known .com?

Tags: dns, subdomain, hosting, web-hosting, domain-name

Regarding dns, resolutions, securities, etc, is there any speed penalty (or another penalty) to use .club (or similar) domain extension instead of well known .com?

Comment: Define "speed". Speed of what? Nameservers do reply differently, but listing TLDs by speed of reply is mostly useless. First because it will depend from where you query, second because it mostly makes no sense as results are cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, your fancy domain of choice is not necessarily slow but it does matter, so do your research over that particular one to make sure it is fast enough.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/bunnycdn.com/blog/is-your-fancy-new-domain-hurting-your-performance-gtld-benchmark/amp/